# pandas, transforming dataframe & combining duplicates with counts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Current dataframe is as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', delimiter=',')

print(df)
idx   uniqueID      String        CaseType 

0        1           'hello1'      1.0
1        1           'hello2'      1.0
2        1           'goodbye1'    1.0
3        1           'goodbye2'    1.0
4        2           'hello1'      3.0
5        2           'hello2'      3.0
6        2           'hello3'      3.0
7        3           'goodbye1'    1.0
8        3           'goodbye2'    1.0
9        3           'goodbye3'    1.0
10       4           'hello'       2.0
11       4           'goodbye'     2.0
```

Expected Output:
(Please note they are grouped based on uniqueID, and the case Type follows the last string of the uniqueID.)

```
idx   Source      Destination 

0        'hello1'     'hello2'
1        'hello2'     'goodbye1'
3        'goodbye1'   'goodbye2'
4        'goodbye2'   '1.0'
6        'hello1'     'hello2'
7        'hello2'     'hello3' 
8        'hello3'     '3.0'
10       'goodbye1'   'goodbye2'
11       'goodbye2'   'goodbye3'
12       'goodbye3'   '1.0'
13       'hello'      'goodbye'
14       'goodbye'    '2.0'
```

**Question: How do I transform the pandas dataframe in this way?**

Currently, I am iterating through every row in a for loop, and for each uniqueId, adding each string+CaseType (at the end) to a list, then splitting up that list and adding it to a new dataframe. It is incredibly slow.

Following this, the next step is to get the total counts/occurences for each row of the output. Essentially, if there are duplicate rows of source:destination (ie, we have 3 rows of 'hello' 'goodbye', it would result in 1 row with 'hello' 'goodbye' with their count as the 3rd column)

Example:

```
Original: 
idx   Source      Destination  

0     'hello1'     'hello2'   
1     'hello2'     'hello3' 
2     'hello1'     'hello2' 
3     'hello4'     'goodbye'  

Expected Output:

idx   Source      Destination  Count

0     'hello1'     'hello2'    2
1     'hello2'     'hello3'    1
2     'hello4'     'goodbye'   1
```

I presume the first step is slightly more complex with pandas logic, and the next step is essentially just combining duplicates and getting their count, but I am new to pandas and not entirely sure how to do either. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify the logic you use to convert from input to output?  From what I can determine, you are simply taking the second entry in the group and making it the destination entry but how do you get count?  Also, what happens if the number of rows in a group are odd?

Comment: It is not just the second entry. All the sources/destinations are grouped based on their unique ID. So for each unique ID, you grab all the strings in their order, add them as i & i+1 for source:destination, then when youve hit the last string for that specific uniqueID, it is that string:CaseType. So for an odd number, like in uniqueID 2, you have 4 rows total. 3 with strings, and the last with the 3rd string:CaseType. Does this make sense? @itprorh66

Comment: And the counts are essentially just the total occurrences of source:destination pairings. So if you've got source/destination as 'hello' 'goodbye' in your dataframe twice, the count would be 2. In SQL logic, it's just a distinct source, destination, count(*), if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```py
df_res = df[["String"]].rename(columns={"String": "Source"})
df_res["Destination"] = (
    df.groupby("uniqueID")["String"].transform("shift", -1)
      .fillna(df["CaseType"])
      .astype("str")
)
```

Result for your sample is:

```
      Source Destination
0     hello1      hello2
1     hello2    goodbye1
2   goodbye1    goodbye2
3   goodbye2         1.0
4     hello1      hello2
5     hello2      hello3
6     hello3         3.0
7   goodbye1    goodbye2
8   goodbye2    goodbye3
9   goodbye3         1.0
10     hello     goodbye
11   goodbye         2.0
```

Regarding the second part: Try

```py
df_counts = (
    df_res.value_counts(["Source", "Destination"])
    .to_frame(name="Counts").reset_index()
)
```

to get

```
     Source Destination  Counts
0  goodbye1    goodbye2       2
1    hello1      hello2       2
2   goodbye         2.0       1
3  goodbye2         1.0       1
4  goodbye2    goodbye3       1
5  goodbye3         1.0       1
6     hello     goodbye       1
7    hello2    goodbye1       1
8    hello2      hello3       1
9    hello3         3.0       1
```

If you want to keep the `Source` and `Destination`columns in the index then remove `.reset_index()` at the end.

Regarding the modification in the comment: You could try more or less the same, but restricted to a filtered `df`:

```py
approved = ["hello1", "hello"]
m = df.groupby("uniqueID")["String"].transform("first").isin(approved)
df_res = df.loc[m, ["String"]].rename(columns={"String": "Source"})
df_res["Destination"] = (
    df[m].groupby("uniqueID")["String"].transform("shift", -1)
      .fillna(df.loc[m, "CaseType"])
      .astype("str")
)
df_res = df_res.reset_index(drop=True)
```

The mask `m` removes those groups whose first row `String` is not in the list of approved strings.

Result:

```
     Source Destination
0    hello1      hello2
1    hello2    goodbye1
2  goodbye1    goodbye2
3  goodbye2         1.0
4    hello1      hello2
5    hello2      hello3
6    hello3         3.0
7     hello     goodbye
8   goodbye         2.0
```

Comment: This seems to be working well, thank you! Just curious. the .value_counts() is converting the df to a series. I am using .to_frame() to convert it back to a df, but it seems to lose the distinct columns in the process. Any idea how to avoid / fix this? @Timus

Comment: @Ev0 Thanks for the feedback. Take a look at the edited answer, maybe that's more like it?

Comment: Amazing! Yes, thanks mate. Marking as answer now.

Comment: curious. In the transforming part, if I wanted to filter it so we only keep the parts where the first string within a uniqueID is within a list, is that easy enough to do? Ie, in the example I gave, we only have 'approved' strings of 'hello1' and 'hello'. So, we would essentially only take data where uniqueID = 1, 2, and 4. But ignore 3.

Comment: @Ev0 I'm not sure I understand completely, but have a look at the edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'idx': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], 'uniqueID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4],
                   'String': ["'hello1'", "'hello2'", "'goodbye1'", "'goodbye2'", "'hello1'", "'hello2'", "'hello3'",
                              "'goodbye1'", "'goodbye2'", "'goodbye3'", "'hello'", "'goodbye'"],
                   'CaseType': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0]}).set_index('idx')

df = df.groupby('uniqueID').apply(
    lambda x: pd.DataFrame({'Source': x.String, 'Destination': x.String.shift(-1, fill_value=f'\'{x.CaseType.iloc[0]}\'')}))
print(df)
```

```
         Source Destination
idx                        
0      'hello1'    'hello2'
1      'hello2'  'goodbye1'
2    'goodbye1'  'goodbye2'
3    'goodbye2'       '1.0'
4      'hello1'    'hello2'
5      'hello2'    'hello3'
6      'hello3'       '3.0'
7    'goodbye1'  'goodbye2'
8    'goodbye2'  'goodbye3'
9    'goodbye3'       '1.0'
10      'hello'   'goodbye'
11    'goodbye'       '2.0'
```